# How to get the Medial Axis from 2D Points

Tags: python, algorithm, matplotlib

I am looking for a method to get the Medial Axis from a height of a blade's  scatter points. The points look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRXqz.jpg)

I have studied some correlated algorithms and tried the Voronoi Algorithm. The result is this picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3hdP.png).

The blue points are my input points and the red ones are Voronoi Vertices.

I have two questions:

1. Why is the result so bad. I hope the result will be like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Gj6.png) This good result's input is not as same as the bad one.
2. How to get the inner Voronoi Vertices instead of all the Voronoi Vertices. The inner Voronoi Vertices should be like the red points in this black inner region.:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29MQB.png)

My algorithm is from https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/280814.280947. The paper name is "A New Voronoi-Based Surface Reconstruction Algorithm".

I hope to get a good Medil Axis from this 2D points which are out of order.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, Delaunay, voronoi_plot_2d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get the input points
point3d = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(r'E:\Evaluation\data\data925\model\cmm_nom\cmm925_nom457.20.ply')
pointCoordinate_3d = np.asarray(point3d.points)
pointCoordinate_2d = pointCoordinate_3d[:, :2]

# Get the Voronoi Diagram 
vor = Voronoi(pointCoordinate_2d)
plt.plot(pointCoordinate_2d[:, 0], pointCoordinate_2d[:, 1], 'b.', markersize=8, label='Point Cloud')
finite_region = np.where(np.all(np.isfinite(vor.vertices), axis=1))
plt.plot(vor.vertices[finite_region, 0], vor.vertices[finite_region, 1], 'r.', markersize=8, label='Voronoi Generator Points')
plt.xlim([pointCoordinate_2d[:, 0].min()-15, pointCoordinate_2d[:, 0].max()+15])
plt.ylim([pointCoordinate_2d[:, 1].min()-15, pointCoordinate_2d[:, 1].max()+15])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The reason you get many Voronoi vertices outside your blue polygon is that the concave part of the polygon (the bottom blue points in your figure) also have Voronoi faces extending below the polygon. Consider, for example three consecutive points in the lower part of the polygon, which construct a flat (concave) triangle. The Voronoi vertex between them will be at the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors (see [wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) for example), which, because of the flatness of the triangle will be far below the points (alternatively you can look at it as the center of the circumscribing circle of the Delaunay triangle).
2. There are several methods to filter points outside a polygon. This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399381/whats-the-fastest-way-of-checking-if-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-in-python) and it's answers will give you several possible solutions.

If you don't have the connectivity of the polygon, i.e., your blue points are not ordered and connected (and possibly even they are), you can also use an approach based on the Alpha Shape.
The following [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50714300/9702190) presents code to compute the Alpha Shape polygon from a scatter of points.
If you use the Alpha Shape, then you can also use a fast in-polygon filter, as implemented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70792636/9702190).

Finally, you can also use the underlying Delaunay triangulation to get the connectivity of the medial axis points themselves, using the connectivity of the Delaunay triangles, which are the dual of the Voronoi vertices.
If this is interesting to you, have a look at my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65777239/9702190), which solves a similar problem in 3D. In particular, modifying the function `compute_voronoi_vertices_and_edges` there, to work on 2D instead of 3D, may actually solve your medial-axis problem.

EDIT: I've modified the `compute_voronoi_vertices_and_edges` function I mentioned above to work on 2D, the code is below. It uses the function `compute_triangle_circumcenters` which is implemented [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65105672/9702190).

```
def compute_voronoi_vertices_and_edges_2d(points, r_thresh=np.inf):
    """
    Compute (finite) Voronoi edges and vertices of a set of points.
    :param points: input points.
    :param r_thresh: radius value for filtering out vertices corresponding to
    Delaunay triangles with large radii of circumscribing circle (alpha-shape condition).
    :return: array of xy Voronoi vertex points and an edge list.
    """
    dt = Delaunay(points)
    xy_centers = compute_triangle_circumcenters(dt.points, dt.simplices)  # uses function from stackoverflow.com/a/65105672/9702190

    # filtering triangles that have radius > thresh
    simp_pts_0 = dt.points[dt.simplices[:, 0]]
    radii = np.linalg.norm(xy_centers - simp_pts_0, axis=1)
    is_in = radii < r_thresh

    # build an edge list from (filtered) triangle neighbor relations
    edge_lst = []
    for i in range(len(dt.neighbors)):
        if not is_in[i]:
            continue  # i is an outside triangle (large radius)
        for j in dt.neighbors[i]:
            if j != -1 and is_in[j]:
                edge_lst.append((i, j))

    return xy_centers, edge_lst
```

Here is an example usage of the function.

```
xy_centers, edge_lst = compute_voronoi_vertices_and_edges_2d(pts_2d, r_thresh=20.)
```

The figure below is the result.
The blue points are the random (but smooth) input points.
The cyan is the underlying Delaunay triangulation, and the black curve is the plot of the medial axis edges, which is what you want.

[image]

Additionally, you can insert the edge list into a [networkx](https://networkx.org/) graph, e.g.:

```
g = nx.Graph(edge_lst)
```

and then use the networkx functionality to go over it.

Comment: @ Iddo Hanniel Thank you for your comment. The blue points are not ordered and connected. I want to use the inside Voronoi vertices as Medial Axis's points, but some inside red points don't seem to belong to the Medial Axis.

Comment: In this case, the Alpha Shape code I referenced can give you an ordered polygon from them (with some suitable alpha radius value) - try it out. If the blue points have some noise in them, then there might be some outlier Voronoi vertices, which you may need to purge away as a post-process.

Comment: I have a question related to this. Do you have time to look it over
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78064735/get-the-center-line-from-some-ordered-scatters

Comment: @Wenllshapion I wrote you an answer there - have a look to see if it answers your question. I'd also appreciate an upvote here.